# Maintaining check state while paging through results

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, express, pagination

To give some background, I am creating a website that allows the user to query for images. The results are shown on a grid of images with checkboxes. The checkboxes are for the user to pick which images they would like to download and a button which zips them up and sends them to the client.  There is also a select and deselect all that allows the user to deselect all images for download. The only way I've done it so far is to send all the results to the user, but paginate them with a show/hide jquery method. It works fine, but it does not work well with many results (>1000) as it still requires to browser to load all those images.

So my question is, if I switch my pagination to only request a given page of about 10 at a time how can I still maintain selection state while allowing the user to continuing to paginate the results?

Comment: Why did you set node.js/express tag? I guess it's client only issue

Comment: Well my first guess would be that you can create another array with some references to selected items. (10 items, 2 selected - another array). So that way, when user move away from selected items you still have track on them, and when he returns on the same page you just have to check if any item in current list have reference in "checked list". And be careful with duplicates :)

Comment: @RaxWunter Well I am using expressjs, I wasn't sure if there was anything I could leverage in expressjs/jade.  I'm fairly new to web development, so I figured it wouldn't hurt.